# Why does my DLL file and its corresponding LIB file have different names?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt file and since I want to prefix the generated DLL and LIB file with "lib" (to be consistent between platforms), I have this statement:

```
if (MSVC)
    # Here, PROJECT_NAME -> "MyLibrary"
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PREFIX "lib")
endif()
```

When I use this file to build my library, the DLL file gets the prefix added to it (eg. `libMyLibrary.dll`), but the LIB file does not have the prefix (eg. `MyLibrary.lib`). Can anyone think of a reason for this issue?

I assumed the `set_target_properties()` call sets the properties for both DLL and LIB files. Thanks!

Comment: The "target" is the output file (the .dll), the lib is not actually the target. You might want the Archive target https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `target` here is only the output file (.dll), you need to also set the ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME

`set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME "lib${PROJECT_NAME}")`

Comment: Thanks! That works. It is interesting that I have to set the Archive target name separately, because in a previous project, I just set the PREFIX property once, and it affected the names of both the DLL and LIB files. I did have both the files output to the same location earlier (not sure if that makes any difference though)